# Where do I find the Haskell packages document in javadoc style?

Tags: haskell, package

[Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/) is great and always be the first place to study how function to be defined and used of specific package.

However, frequently, we need refers multi-packages simultaneously, e.g. Control.Monad, Data.List and ... so on, and switches among of them. The easy way to do that is open mulit-tabs in chrome, but as the number of tabs grow, there are many tabs be opened and the name of package on the tab cannot be showed fully.

So, Are there exist some web sites organize Haskell packages documents like [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) style, we can browse and select packages in right frame and show the content of document in left frame. Furthermore, it is more appreciated if it can save and list frequent use package document in another frame.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use [Dash](https://kapeli.com/dash) but technically that's just downloading it from Hackage, you can also [build docs locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454793/haskell-offline-documentation?rq=1) (if library has them) but I find those a little cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks for info, but does it has documents describe how to use it?

Comment: I'm not sure now I look, go into the preferences of the app and on the download tab you can download all the docsets you require or even straight to a repo. For example some of the ones I have are Haskell, Yesod, Persistent, Esquelito...  hope that helps

Comment: @assembly.jc https://zealdocs.org/ is a cross-platform client. (I personally don't find it useful, though.)

Comment: or alternatively you could manually download them all for offline usage as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454793/haskell-offline-documentation?rq=1

Comment: @leftaroundabout I tried Zeal but it only has the packages in the Haskell Platform. That's nice, but a lot of packages are missing. I guess Dash has the same issue, since they share the docs (AFAICS).

Comment: @cmdv Thank for your help, it is no different for us whether documents are offline or online. I think I need to do it for myself, maybe someone has done the same thing, we are just reinvent the wheel.